# Why do we use phenolphthalein as an acid-base indicator?

Tags: acid-base, ph

It seems that no resource I come across addresses the fact that the pH range for phenolphthalein's color change is around 8.2-10. In other words, it's still colorless at 8.2. Why then, is it claimed that the indicator changes colors when the solution changes from an acid to a base? Wouldn't you want an indicator that changes colors at about pH 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you analyse a titration curve you will immediately notice the pH shooting up near equivalence point. For this reason, there is very little difference to the amount of base added for pH 7 and pH 8 (due to the logarithmic nature of pH). So, it's not entirely accurate but certainly good enough (for strong acid - strong base and weak acid - strong base), if you want something better use an electronic pH tester

Comment: Looking at a titration curve clears up a bit of my confusion, but now I'm wondering what the point is of having an indicator at all. If the "volume added" in this graph--http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/sawb2.gif--matches up with all those different pH values, what's the point of trying to get it close to 7?

Comment: I believe the link was distorted: http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/sawb2.gif

Comment: pH 7 is the equivalence point where the moles of H+ in the original solution equals the moles of OH- added, so we can construct an equation and solve for unknown

Comment: [volume of solution][conc(H+)] = [volume of added solution][conc(OH-)]

Comment: If you're wondering about that specific curve, the volume added is only specific to specific concentration of base, specific concentration of the acid, specific volume of acid. The volume added values all change based on the other 3 "variables"

Comment: Right, but if it didn't matter that we were at pH 8 with phenolphthalein, my question is why bother with accuracy? Why is such a big deal made when the solution becomes too pink (passed equivalence point)?

Comment: Due to the way the pH system works, the overshoot of base increases exponentially with an increase in pH. In this case, pH 10 contains around 100x more overshoot base than pH 8, which is quite often a significant amount (for precise measurements). (You can work this out by converting pH to pOH then finding concentration of hydroxide ions)

Comment: Say we have 1L of solution, with pH 8 it would be around 0.00001 moles NaOH (a very small amount), with pH 10 around 0.001 moles, at lot more. Say we overshoot to 11, that would be 0.01, pH 12 around 0.1 moles). Although an error of 0.01 right now may seem small, the concentration and volume of the initial acid is not likely to be high, which makes the error worse after we try to solve for what we want

Comment: Looking at the title, the other half of the answer should be that there are few indicators that go from colorless to a color. Phenolphthalein's color change is very easily detectable visually.

Comment: I think what OP was asking was since phenolphthalein only tested 8.2-10, why would it be used, as that directly relates to the post

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine what indicator to use, you have to identify the reactants and strong or weak. For a strong base and strong acid reaction the pH shift will likely occur around 7. If its a strong acid vs a weak base, then the pH will probably lower than 7.